# Update a column if a row is not a duplicate, or a row's ID isn't a certain number in SQL SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, and I would like the following update command to set `isExcluded = 1` to all rows where `PhoneID` and `PhoneName` are not duplicates and all rows where the `ID` doesn't not have the smallest number from a selected `PhoneID` if those rows do not have a duplicate `PhoneID` and `PhoneName` (i.e.: since all rows with `PhoneID = 2` are not duplicates, the row containing `PhoneName = b` has the smallest ID, since it's `ID = 3`. Therefore, all rows with `PhoneID = 2` and `ID > 3` will have their `IsExcluded` set to `1`).

| ID | PhoneID | PhoneName | isExcluded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | a | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | b | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | c | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | d | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | e | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | c | 0 |
| 8 | 3 | c | 0 |
| 9 | 3 | d | 0 |
| 10 | 3 | d | 0 |

Here's my SQL script that I wrote. It only seems to get the non-duplicates only.

```sql
WITH Duplicates AS
(
    SELECT
        ID, PhoneID, PhoneName, isExcluded,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PhoneName, PhoneID ORDER BY ID)) AS RowNum
    FROM
        Phones
)
UPDATE Phones
SET isExcluded = 1
FROM Duplicates d
WHERE (
d.PhoneID = Phones.PhoneID     
AND d.PhoneName = Phones.PhoneName 
AND d.RowNum =< 1);

SELECT * FROM Phones;
```

This table should be the result of my command.

| ID | PhoneID | PhoneName | isExcluded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | a | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | b | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | c | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | d | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | e | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | c | 0 |
| 8 | 3 | c | 0 |
| 9 | 3 | d | 1 |
| 10 | 3 | d | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be a variation of a *gaps and islands* problem, which you can solve by first grouping the partitions and then using an updatable CTE to assign the `isExcluded` value

```
with gp as (
    select *, 
      Row_Number() over(order by id) 
      - Row_Number() over(partition by phoneid, phonename order by id) gp
    from t
), p as (
    select *, 
      case when Min(gp) over(partition by phoneid) <gp then 1 end IsEx
    from gp
)
update p set isExcluded = isEx
where IsEx = 1
```

See [working DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e7d4f86111c1ed641b27449f2a18803)

Comment: Works fine! What if instead setting a column's isExcluded to 1, we set the PhoneID to be equal to the row's ID?

Comment: That's not what you asked, but you can easily amend it to be `then id end IsEx` and `where IsEx is not null` and update whatever column you like.

Comment: I know that it's not what I asked, I was just wondering if it's possible. Thank you so much!

Comment: Everything is possible, except where it's not :)